# how to get drawer over header in react navigation v5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

Here is my code

```
export const DrawerStack = () => {
  return (
<Drawer.Navigator
      drawerStyle={{backgroundColor: BLUE_COLOR_1}}
      drawerContentOptions={{labelStyle: {color: '#FFF'}}}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={HOME_SCREEN}
        component={HomeTopTabNavigator}

      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={WALLET}
        component={Wallet}
        options={{title: 'Wallet'}}
      />...
```

Then I am referencing it in a stack screen which I wrapped in a stack navigator

```
<Stack.Navigator><Stack.Screen
        name={HOME_STACK_SCREEN}
        component={DrawerStack}
```

I tried following [How to get drawer over the header in react navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306084/how-to-get-drawer-over-the-header-in-react-navigation) but these soon won't work in v5 as navigator can't have another navigator as direct child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your stack inside drawer instead of drawer inside stack

```
- Drawer
  - Stack
    - Home
    - Wallet
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/nesting-navigators.html#parent-navigators-ui-is-rendered-on-top-of-child-navigator

> v5 as navigator can't have another navigator as direct child

You don't need direct child. Put the stack inside a screen.

Comment: can you show some code. I visited the url you mentioned but i dont get it